# How to get user input in a textbox from another form?

Tags: c#

I'd like to display the value from a textbox to a textbox in a different form. I entered this code into the second form (the first form being the one with the textbox I'm getting the value from):

```
private void Form2_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frm = new Form1();
    textBox.Text = frm.textBox1.Text;
}
```

What I need to display is the user input though, and the textBox only displays the declared value of textBox1.

Comment: This is because you are doing this on `Form2_Load` event, you may create the secondary form there, but you'll have to update the textbox on an user input event

Answer (score 1):

This creates a *new instance* of `Form1`:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
```

Nothing was entered into any input in *that* instance, so there's no value in `frm.textBox1.Text`.  What you need is a reference to the *existing* instance.

Presumably `Form1` is creating/showing `Form2`?  (Or, at the very least, they are created/shown by some common container/parent?)  If `Form2` needs a reference to `Form1`, have it require one when it's created.  For example, a constructor parameter:

```
private Form1 form1Instance { get; set; }

private Form2 () { }

public Form2 (Form1 form1)
{
    this.form1Instance = form1;
}
```

Then when you create an instance of `Form2` you'd have to supply it with that dependency:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
```

or

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(someInstanceOfForm1);
```

Then in `Form2` you can reference the instance which was supplied:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox.Text = this.form1Instance.textBox1.Text;
}
```